# Get a list of mat file variables without loading the full file in python

Tags: python, scipy

I have a very big matlab data file(2GB) which I need to load in python with `scipy.io.loadmat`. It returns `MemoryError`. It is surely because the file is too big, loading it in matlab in the same machine return memory error, either.

But load a sequence of variables of this file succeed like this, `scipy,io,loadmat('data.mat',variable_names='var1')`. So I need get a list of all variables inside a mat file, without first loading the file, `then data.keys()`.

Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a list of all the variables in a `.mat` file, you can use [`scipy.io.whosmat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.io.whosmat.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np, scipy.io
>>> md = {"A": np.random.random((100,3)), "B": np.zeros((1,2,3), dtype=int)}
>>> scipy.io.savemat("test.mat", md)
>>> scipy.io.whosmat("test.mat")
[('A', (100, 3), 'double'), ('B', (1, 2, 3), 'int32')]
```

(Whether this is the best approach to your actual problem, I've no idea.)